# jQuery Ajax Post Bootstrap Popover Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a e-commerce system. And i'm adding products to my cart like on screenshot[image]

When i click to add to cart button. I'm showing a shopping cart notification which is bootstrap popover. The main problem is when i decide to another product i recived same notification.

I'm writing "Product A is added." When i do that in every different product adding it writes Product A is added. Adding i correct but notification is wrong.

Here is my jQuery Code...

```
$('.quick-add-cart').click(function(){ //Sepete Ekleme İşlemi yapıyoruz.
     $('#cart-popover').attr('data-content','');
     productID  = $(this).parents('.productbit').attr('id');
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/add_to_cart.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {            
              productID : productID
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
              if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   alert('Bağlantı sağlanamadı.\n Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz.');
          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
              alert('Sayfa bulunamadı. [404]');
          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
              alert('Sunucu Hatası [500].');
          } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
              alert('Requested JSON parse failed.'+ jqXHR.responseText);
          } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
              alert('Time out error.');
          } else if (exception === 'abort') {
              alert('Ajax istemi durduruldu.');
          } else {
              alert('Beklenmeyen Hata.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
          }
          },
          success: function (data) {
              if (data.insert_count > 0) {
                  cart_old_count = $('#cart_count').text();
                  cart_new_count = parseInt(cart_old_count,10) + data.insert_count;
                      $('#cart_count').text(cart_new_count);
              }
                  $('#cart-popover').attr('data-content',data.queryresult).popover('show');
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
                  }, 5000);
              }
                            });
                       });
```

And here is my add_to_cart.php

```
require_once '../includes/class/class.cart.php';
        include_once '../locale.php';

        session_start();
        $C = new Cart(); 

//Sepete Ürün Ekliyoruz
if (isset($_POST['productID'])){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        $jsonData['queryresult'] = "Sepete Ekleme Yapabilmek için Bayi Girişi Yapmalısınız !";
    } else {
        $productid = $_POST['productID'];
        $product   = $C->get_product_fields('product', $productid);

        $jsonData['update_count'] = 0;
        $jsonData['insert_count'] = 0;

        $cart_error = FALSE;

        if ($C->is_in_cart($productid)) {
            if ($C->update_cart($productid))
                $jsonData['update_count'] += 1;
            else {
                $jsonData['queryresult'] = $C->cart_errors($productid);
                $cart_error = TRUE;
            }
        } else {
            if ($C->add_to_cart($productid))
                $jsonData['insert_count'] += 1;
            else {
                $jsonData['queryresult'] = $C->cart_errors($productid);
                $cart_error = TRUE;
            }
        }

        if ($cart_error === FALSE) {
            if ($jsonData['insert_count'] == 1){
                $jsonData['queryresult'] = "Bir paket ".$product." eklendi.";
            }

            if ($jsonData['update_count'] == 1){
                $jsonData['queryresult'] = "Bir paket daha ".$product." eklendi.";
            }

            if ($jsonData['insert_count'] == 0 && $jsonData['update_count'] == 0){
                $jsonData['queryresult'] = "Ürünü sepete ekleme sırasında hata oldu.";
            }
        }
    }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($jsonData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

related issue: [Twitter bootstrap js popover content doesn't update when data-content attribute is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859267/twitter-bootstrap-js-popover-content-doesnt-update-when-data-content-attribute)

Two changes are required to solve your problem:

1. Instead of `.attr('data-content', data.queryresult)`, you should use `.data('content', data.queryresult)`
2. You need to use `.popover('destroy')` before updating the content, this prevents `popover` from getting lost with async processing.

Here is a sample code, I have used setTimeout to simulate the Ajax call:

```
function displayPopover(msg) {
  $('#cart-popover').popover('destroy');
  $('#cart-popover').data('content',msg).popover('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
      $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
  }, 5000);
}

// add first product to cart
setTimeout(function() { displayPopover('product 1') }, 2000);

// add second product to cart
setTimeout(function() { displayPopover('product 2') }, 4000);
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/UXAxEBE/1/

tip: when you have such type of error where you don't know whether the problem is at php or javascript side, you should try to `console.log(data.queryresult)` in your javascript to validate that php returns the correct content and that your problem is at client side.

Comment: i didn't use data function before. I read the jQuery Data manuel. I applied it. But now there is no result :) Blank Only...

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$('#cart-popover').attr('data-content',data.queryresult)` by `$('#cart-popover').data('content', data.queryresult)` ?

Comment: I tested and found out that it was also needed to call .popover('destroy'), cf. answer. Next time include a jsfiddle, it will speed things up.